# Pull a list of values from array, eliminating dooblons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a full array of dishes. All dishes have a category they belong to, and several dishes can belong to a same category. 
How can I generate a list of those categories (`dishCategory` in list below) using the array of dishes and pull it to my  controller, eliminating any dooblons ? (i have hard-coded as of now, but it is highly inefficient). Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xv2BC2D7xzx7nUMENokJ?p=preview) to illustrate my case

**DISHLIST.js :**

```
angular.module('wmapp.factory_dishes', [])

wmapp.factory('dishesFactory', function () {
    "use strict";
    var factory = {
            dishes : [
                {nameEnglish: 'TAPENADE', nameLocal: 'Tapenade', description: 'xxxxxx',  region: 'Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur', regioncode: 'FR.B8', itemid: 'FR002', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Bakery', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'},
                {nameEnglish: 'GREEK STYLE MUSHROOMS  ', nameLocal: 'xxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR003', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Pie / pizza', country: 'France', type: ''},
                {nameEnglish: 'HAM & CHEESE TOASTED SANDWICHS / WITH EGGS', nameLocal: 'Croque Monsieur / Croque Madame', description: 'xxxxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR005', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Sandwich', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ONION SOUP', nameLocal: 'Soupe à l’oignon', description: 'xxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR008', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Pie / pizza', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'}
                {nameEnglish: 'VEAL ESCALOPE WITH CREAMY MUSHROOM DRESSING', nameLocal: 'xxxxx',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR047', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Side dish', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ROASTED PORK WITH PRUNES', nameLocal: 'Roti de porc aux pruneaux', description: ' ',  region: 'Poitou-Charentes', regioncode: 'FR.B7', itemid: 'FR048', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Side dish', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'STUFFED TOMATOES', nameLocal: 'Tomates farcies', description: 'xxxx',  region: 'All ', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR049', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'VEAL PAUPIETTES', nameLocal: '  ',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR050', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ROAST LEG OF LAMB', nameLocal: 'Gigot d’agneau', description: 'xxxxxx.',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR051', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'},
                {nameEnglish: 'BAKED WITLOF AND HAM', nameLocal: 'Gratin d’endives au jambon', description: 'xxxxxx ',  region: 'Nord-Pas-de-Calais', regioncode: 'FR.B4', itemid: 'FR052', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'SMOKED PORK WITH GREEN LENTILS', nameLocal: 'Petit sale aux lentilles', description: 'xxxx',  region: 'Auvergne', regioncode: 'FR.98', itemid: 'FR053', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'BLUE RIBBON', nameLocal: 'Cordon bleu', description: 'xxxxxx',  region: 'All ', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR054', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France'},

            ],
            getDishes : function () {
                return factory.dishes;
            },
            getDish : function (itemid) {
                var dish = {};
                angular.forEach(factory.dishes, function (value, key) {
                    if (value.itemid === itemid) {
                        dish = value;
                    }
                });

                return dish;
            }
        };
    return factory;
});
```

**CONTROLLER FOR DISH CATEGORIES:**

```
 var wmapp = angular.module('app', []);

// dishlistcontroller 
 wmapp.controller('dishTypeListController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.dishTypeList = [
        {'name': 'Bakery'},
        {'name': 'Beverage'},
        {'name': 'Meat'},
        {'name': 'Pastry'},
        {'name': 'Pie / pizza'},
        {'name': 'Salads'},
        {'name': 'Sandwich'}
    ];
    $scope.selection = [];


})
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just leave it to lib like underscore or lodash to do this type of things, but you can definitely do this using plain vanilla js like user3906922 suggested.

See below (and open your console to see the result...):

```js
var dishes = [
                {nameEnglish: 'TAPENADE', nameLocal: 'Tapenade', description: 'xxxxxx',  region: 'Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur', regioncode: 'FR.B8', itemid: 'FR002', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Bakery', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'},
                {nameEnglish: 'GREEK STYLE MUSHROOMS  ', nameLocal: 'xxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR003', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Pie / pizza', country: 'France', type: ''},
                {nameEnglish: 'HAM & CHEESE TOASTED SANDWICHS / WITH EGGS', nameLocal: 'Croque Monsieur / Croque Madame', description: 'xxxxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR005', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Sandwich', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ONION SOUP', nameLocal: 'Soupe à l’oignon', description: 'xxxxx',  region: 'All', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR008', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Pie / pizza', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'},
                {nameEnglish: 'VEAL ESCALOPE WITH CREAMY MUSHROOM DRESSING', nameLocal: 'xxxxx',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR047', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Side dish', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ROASTED PORK WITH PRUNES', nameLocal: 'Roti de porc aux pruneaux', description: ' ',  region: 'Poitou-Charentes', regioncode: 'FR.B7', itemid: 'FR048', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Side dish', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'STUFFED TOMATOES', nameLocal: 'Tomates farcies', description: 'xxxx',  region: 'All ', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR049', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'VEAL PAUPIETTES', nameLocal: '  ',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR050', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'ROAST LEG OF LAMB', nameLocal: 'Gigot d’agneau', description: 'xxxxxx.',  region: 'Lower Normandy', regioncode: 'FR.99', itemid: 'FR051', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France', type: 'top_10'},
                {nameEnglish: 'BAKED WITLOF AND HAM', nameLocal: 'Gratin d’endives au jambon', description: 'xxxxxx ',  region: 'Nord-Pas-de-Calais', regioncode: 'FR.B4', itemid: 'FR052', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Meat', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'SMOKED PORK WITH GREEN LENTILS', nameLocal: 'Petit sale aux lentilles', description: 'xxxx',  region: 'Auvergne', regioncode: 'FR.98', itemid: 'FR053', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France'},
                {nameEnglish: 'BLUE RIBBON', nameLocal: 'Cordon bleu', description: 'xxxxxx',  region: 'All ', regioncode: '', itemid: 'FR054', cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',  dishCategory: 'Main', country: 'France'},

            ];
  
  var categories = _.chain(dishes)  //Easier chaining in underscore so I don't have to pass the array to subsequent calls..
    .map(function(d) { return { name : d.dishCategory }; })  //pull out the dishCategory and return it in the desired format
    .uniq(function(c) { return c.name; })  //ensure that the new category list is unique
    .sort(function(c) { return c.name; })  //extra credit... sort it
    .value();  //finally, get it out of underscore into a proper category array... [ { name: 'blah' }, {name : 'blah1'} ]
  
  console.log(categories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function on your factory which get distinct dish categories :

```
getCategories: function() {
    var categories = [], o = {};
    angular.forEach(factory.dishes, function (value, key) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(value.dishCategory)) {
            return;
        }
        categories.push(value.dishCategory);
        o[value.dishCategory] = true;
    });
    return categories;
}
```

Then inject that factory to your controller, and call that function:

```
wmapp.controller('dishTypeListController', function ($scope, $rootScope, dishesFactory) {
    "use strict";

    $scope.selection = [];
    $scope.categories = dishesFactory.getCategories();

})
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mcXMGPdnswgxbLNDb0P?p=preview).

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what I need,  will look at it when I return  to my laptop  and update  my response

Comment: Indeed works fine on Plunker, however in my real life app, i have a filter implemented on my categories, and cannot make the function work. I have added (commented out) the controller coded is the script.js file here : http://plnkr.co/edit/nW0y1ZzgcmRjBlJ6xpBo?p=preview. May be I need to include "dihesFactory" in a parameter of a function ?

Comment: well you can use the factory function on the filtered results no?

Comment: well, the filter is run based on the factory function output. You can see the filter in action here : http://plnkr.co/edit/gnTHAtIrKlgRUS7ykLeB?p=preview. I am not quite sure how to integrate the solution you proposed (which seems to be perfectly suited though)